# Three textboxes for a date of birth field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am investigating ways of introducing date of birth validation into my applications.  I have recently got DatePicker working, however my research is telling me that a lot of modern web apps use three distinct fields for dates.  I have a date of birth field and I have done this in JavaScript:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test').click(function(event) {
    var daySelector = "#dd",
      monthSelector = "#mm",
      yearSelector = "#yyyy";
    var day = $(daySelector).val() == "" ? 1 : parseInt($(daySelector).val(), 10);
    var month = $(monthSelector).val() == "" ? 1 : parseInt($(monthSelector).val(), 10);
    month = month - 1;
    alert(month);
    var year = parseInt($(yearSelector).val(), 10);
    var date = new Date(year, month, day);
    var result = (date.getFullYear() == year) && (date.getMonth() == month) && (date.getDate() == day);
    $('#result').append("<br>result: " + result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-inputs">
  <input type="text" id="dd" name="dd" placeholder="DD" maxlength="2" value="30">
  <input type="text" id="mm" name="mm" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" value="02">
  <input type="text" id="yyyy" name="yyyy" placeholder="YYYY" value="2000" maxlength="4">
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="test" name="test" value="test">
</div>
```

It seems to work nicely.  How would I integrate this with an MVC Core 2.1 application bearing in mind that my model has a datetime field for the date of birth.  Should I be storing the date of birth as three fields in the database? Is there a JQuery library that can help me?

Comment: Consider whether datepickers are appropriate for DOB fields in the first place. I wouldn't want to click the previous year button... many times... to select my birth year. Datepickers are most useful when day of the week and/or week of the month are a consideration in the selection of a date, not when the date is fixed.

Comment: @Isherwood, thanks.  Do you know of any .JQuery libraries that could help me with a three field date?

Comment: You could use dropdowns for the values as it makes validation easier. To send this to your server logic use 3 ints and convert to a DateTime when the request is sent. Then you can validate the resulting Date is valid, ie. not 31/02/2018. Then store it in the backend as a DateTime.

Comment: Are you ever going to be displaying the date of birth in the three field format?

Comment: Storing DOB as three separate fields is never advised. You will end up missing all the date dependent operations that the database offers you.

Comment: @Tapler, yes.  I will need an edit fwebpage.

Comment: I don't like dropdowns for days or years, either, for the same reason. Scrolling half a mile is not simpler than typing two or four digits.

Comment: @isherwood you can still type to select an option if they're designed properly.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, would the .NET Core model have three ints for the date?

Comment: Yes, but they don't add value or simplicity, except maybe for mobile.

Comment: @w0051977 yes. You can provide the normal int arguments for year, month, day, hour, minute etc. to the DateTime contructor.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, are you saying the view model would have three fields for the date of birth and the domain model (mapped to the database) would have one field (datetime) for the date of birth? Thanks.

Comment: I'd advise to stick with a single field. If you use the `date` input type, every modern browser and every mobile browser will provide a control that will handle validation for you. Admittedly, the experience isn't the best for something like a DOB when using the actual calendar, since you have to jump back a bunch of years (though some browsers handle it better than others). However, the user can always manually type in the field, and the input will be handled distinctly for the month, day and year components (user doesn't have to worry about slashes, dash, et al.

Comment: The best part though is that you can then also set `autocomplete="bday"` and if the user has already set their birth date in the browser, it will autocomplete there for them.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, it seems that most modern browsers usr three fields e.g. confused.com.  Can you point me to one modern web app that uses a datepicker? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. The browser does nothing unless it has a `date` input type. Then, it will typically add a text input control that actually edits day month and year individually, but all within the same input box, not in three separate boxes. When you click on this input, you'll also get a calendar picker popup, generally. The experience might be slightly different browser to browser or desktop vs. mobile, but that's the norm.